# Compress image after capturing from camera and storing it at given path

Tags: android, image, camera, compression

I'm working on an android app which needs a photo to be taken from camera and compress it and then store it to the given path.I'm a beginner in android ,so I'll be thankful for any kind of help .I'm able to take the picture and store it on sdcard ,but can't find a way to compress it .I want to upload the image to server so want to compress the image as low as 50kb.I tried many solutions on the internet but none could do the thing .

Comment: Add your effort .

Comment: `.I tried many solutions` then you have to add what you have tried, or you will get answers with the solutions you have already tried

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko I tried the Bitmap.createScaledBitmap() thing and also BitmapFactory inSampleSize thing from different examples

Comment: and what didn't work there? `createScaledBitmap` is a correct approach

Comment: have to pass a Bitmap over there and what I get in onActivityResult is the Uri of the image . How to convert that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer [this](http://voidcanvas.com/whatsapp-like-image-compression-in-android/) link to achieve image compression.
I have implemented this code in my project and able to compress an image by maintaining quality.

```
  FileOutputStream out = null;
    String filename = getFilename();
    try {
        out = new FileOutputStream(filename);
        scaledBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, out);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

You can change number 80 as per your requirements.
This number indicates quality of the compressed image.
quality must be in the range 0-100.
0 meaning compress for small size, 100 meaning compress for max quality.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use bitmap compression 0 = MAX compression and 100 = Least Compression. I hope this will help you

```
public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.WEBP, 0, bytes);
    String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
    return Uri.parse(path);
}
```

Comment: how do I pass the image Uri as a Bitmap ?

Comment: extract bitmap from that URI

Comment: Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), uri);